Determining the significance of a curve's factors
Given the equation $x^2+x+1$ you could easily determine that $x^2$ will have the greatest overall impact on the curve--then $x$ and finally $1$. And this holds true for any coefficients present as the curve approaches infinity; however, I'm interested in determining the factors with the most significance in a finite window.
Given the equation $\sin(x)-\cos(x)^2$ how would you determine which factor contributes more to the result and is therefore more significant?
The solution I've worked out this morning is to take the area between the original curve, and the curve without the factor we're testing for significance. For example, if I wanted to test the significance of the $sin(x)$ I'd use the following integral:
Original curve: $f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)^2$
Difference curve: $g(x)=f(x)-\sin(x)$
$$\int_a^b{f(x)-g(x)dx}$$
However, because arbitrary curves could intersect an arbitrary amount of times, it needs to account for which function is above at all times:
$$\int_a^b\max(f(x),g(x))-\min(f(x),g(x))dx$$
For an a and b of $0$ and $2\pi$ I get an area of $4$
If I wanted to test the significance of $\cos(x)^2$, $g(x)$ would become $f(x)-\cos(x)^2$ and for the same a and b I get an area of 3.14159. Therefore, the factor of $\sin(x)$ is more significant than $\cos(x)^2$ because it contributes a greater change in area
Here's a desmos graph with an interactive demonstration https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q1mqz5xrwu
So here's my question(s)
Is this a valid method for determining the significance of different factors of an equation? What other methods exist? Where could I go for further research (as I couldn't find much from searching, although I am not too knowledgeable in mathematical lingo). Have I made any rudimentary mistakes in my calculus (I'm a year rusty).

Thanks @Simon for the Latex edits. What do the prefixed "/" do?

sin gives $sin$ while \sin gives $\sin$. The latter is more beautiful, in my opinion.

Agreed, makes it look more like a math symbol as opposed to a function.
